# Npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1: Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When i install

```
npm install browserify babelify babel-preset-es2015
```

i'm facing following warning message

**npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!**

how to resolve the warning?

Comment: Instructions for resolving this are literally provided in the deprecation notice... does it really warrant a question/answer?

Comment: Really it's needed, for more importantly beginners. @Felix Kling

Comment: IMO your answer provides less information than the deprecation message itself.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, please edit the same. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution after my Research

```
npm install browserify babelify babel-preset-env
```